# How to dynamically trim decimal places from varchar column within Snowflake?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running into an issue I'm really stumped on.  We store area points within 1 column in Snowflake.

**Example stored as a varchar:**

MULTIPOLYGON (((
-103.13610284560149 32.725882872864453
, -103.14470012813675 32.725738931539986
, -103.14475163540753 32.732599004640321
, -103.13626891853778 32.732448970077257
, -103.1361028456015  32.725882872864453
, -103.13610284560149 32.725882872864453)))

Snowflake has some built in Geography/Geospatial functions, however it doesn't allow for an area to have overlapping lines.

```
SELECT TO_GEOGRAPHY('MULTIPOLYGON (((
  -103.13610284560149 32.725882872864453
, -103.14470012813675 32.725738931539986
, -103.14475163540753 32.732599004640321
, -103.13626891853778 32.732448970077257
, -103.1361028456015  32.725882872864453
, -103.13610284560149 32.725882872864453)))')
```

Running the code above in Snowflake returns:

SQL Error [100217] [P0000]: Geography validation failed: Edge (-103.136103,32.725883) -- (-103.144700,32.725739) crosses edge (-103.136269,32.732449) -- (-103.136103,32.725883)

There are 6 points in this area, point #5 is almost on top of point 6 so it overlaps and throws the error.  I've asked the business area that cares about this data to try and store the data with less precision as 13 decimal places is far too accurate, but I'm left with the task of how to clean this up.

These areas are unique, however most are squares, but they can have any number of points.  There are areas that have 3 points to over 50 thousand.  I've used Snowflake's SPLIT_TO_TABLE to try and parse each coordinate pair to their own row but then I can't split the subsequent rows out.

**I've run this:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DATABASE.SCHEMA.GEOGRAPHYSTUFF AS
SELECT  table1.value
FROM TABLE(split_to_table(
(
SELECT 'MULTIPOLYGON (((
  -103.13610284560149 32.725882872864453
, -103.14470012813675 32.725738931539986
, -103.14475163540753 32.732599004640321
, -103.13626891853778 32.732448970077257
, -103.1361028456015  32.725882872864453
, -103.13610284560149 32.725882872864453)))'
), ',')) AS table1;
   

   WITH cte AS (
   SELECT SPLIT(VALUE, ' ')::VARCHAR AS POINTS
   FROM DATABASE.SCHEMA.GEOGRAPHYSTUFF
   )
   
   Select SPLIT(POINTS, ',')
   FROM cte
```

Which then includes special characters, when pasted it looks like this:

```
[
  "[\"MULTIPOLYGON\"",
  "\"(((\\r\\n\"",
  "\"\"",
  "\"-103.13610284560149\"",
  "\"32.725882872864453\\r\\n\"]"
]
```

I am not sure that this can be solved completely within Snowflake.  I am thinking that I might need to use Python or PowerShell to create a table for each area and then handle the data transformations within the script rather than Snowflake, then insert the cleaned data into Snowflake. Does anyone have any thoughts or recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not that the points are almost identical. It's that point #5 has a lower x value than point #6, which makes an illegal path. If it was exactly identical to or higher than the final x value, it would work.

Assuming it's just some rounding issue at the 13th decimal and that the points are in the correct order otherwise, you can truncate away one (or more) decimals with `regexp_replace` to make it work.

```
select
    'MULTIPOLYGON ((( -103.13610284560149 32.725882872864453 , -103.14470012813675 32.725738931539986 , -103.14475163540753 32.732599004640321 , -103.13626891853778 32.732448970077257 , -103.1361028456015 32.725882872864453 , -103.13610284560149 32.725882872864453)))' as value,
    to_geography(regexp_replace(value, '[0-9]{1}([^\\d\.])', '\\1'))
```

Comment: That solved my issue!  Some areas we have are legitimately bad and cross when they shouldn't, but your solution allowed me to get these precision errors resolved. 

Thanks so much!